# Error when using DOMDocument with XPath & DOMDocument to get td(style) tag?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$content = '
<table width="100%" border="0"> 
   <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap;" class="cap_row_odd">browser_id</td>
      <td width="100%" class="cap_row_odd">browser_winmo_iemobile9</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="white-space:nowrap;" class="cap_row_even  cap_isempty"><span>nokia_feature_pack</span></td>                
      <td width="100%" class="cap_row_even cap_isempty"></td>             
   </tr>
</table>
';
```

And I using DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$attributes = array();

$query1 = $xpath->query("//td[@style='white-space:nowrap']");
foreach($query1 as $a) { 
    $attributes[] = $a->nodeValue;
}

print_r($attributes);
```

=> But result is null, How to get it?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon (`;`) in your xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing a `;` from the xpath query:

```
$query1 = $xpath->query("//td[@style='white-space:nowrap;']"); // works
```

Consider using the [contains()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function to make your query more robust:

```
$query1 = $xpath->query("//td[contains(@style, 'white-space:nowrap')]"); // works too
```